# Getting rid of gaps between images in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, image

I'm making a printable certificate. Since background images aren't enabled by default I'm making a border by placing img tags.

For some reason there are gaps of a few pixels between the img tags...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chGzP/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to make your images block elements:

```
img { display: block; }
```

and it'll all fall into line. Images are by default inline elements, so as Xavi said you're getting white space in there from your line breaks. Of course if there'll be any other images involved, you'll need to refine your selector.

Comment: saved me hours of fruitless trial and error coding. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: relative;` to shift your images to fill the gap

```
#bottom_border{
   position: relative; 
   bottom: 5px;
 }

#top_border{
   position: relative; 
   top: 5px;
 }
```

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chGzP/5/)

Comment: This solution is very brittle.  The `top` and `bottom` values are *very* dependent on the current font size.  I'd suggest using another solution.

Comment: @Xavi are you aware of CSS positioning?

Comment: Yes I am.  I've adjusted the font size to be `18px`.  Note how the gap on the bottom image has reappeared: http://jsfiddle.net/FAZyL/

Comment: @Xavi when you increase font-size, padding of the element, you need to reset your positioning again, that's pure css basics...

Answer (score 3):

set `Vertical-align` in your `#top_border` and `#bottom_border` as

```
#top_border{ vertical-align:bottom}
#bottom_border{vertical-align:top}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chGzP/10/) here

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `font-size: 0` to `#certificate`.  The gaps you see are actually spaces (the character).  I fully admit that setting the font size to zero is a bit of a hack.  Fortunately, when the [white-space rules](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#white-space-rules) for css3 are fully supported, you can use [`text-space-collapse: collapse`](http://realworldvalidator.com/css/module/Text/text-space-collapse) instead.

Comment: I've actually been told the opposite.  When setting a property to `0`, leave the units off -- it's more concise and is interpreted the same.  What's the rational behind adding `px`?  Are there some browser compatibility issues?

Comment: yes, mostly when using `<! DOCTYPE html>` ..when I made a website using HTML5 doctype, it neveer respected any values if I missed out the `px`

Answer (score 1):

add

```
#certificate img { display: block; }
```

to the end of the css